# Why does the shared pointer does not delete memory?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

> ```
> shared_ptr<string> pNico(new string("Nico"));
> shared_ptr<string> pJutta(new string("Jutta"));
> // put them multiple times in a container
> vector<shared_ptr<string>> whoMadeCoffee;
> whoMadeCoffee.push_back(pJutta);
> whoMadeCoffee.push_back(pJutta);
> whoMadeCoffee.push_back(pNico);
> whoMadeCoffee.push_back(pJutta);
> whoMadeCoffee.push_back(pNico);
>
> pNico = nullptr;         
> whoMadeCoffee.resize(2);
> ```
>
> At the end of the program, when the last owner of the string gets destroyed, the shared pointer calls delete for the object it refers to. Such a deletion does not necessarily have to happen at the end of the scope. For example, assigning the nullptr to `pNico` or resizing the vector so that it contains only the first two element s would delete the last owner of the string initialized with `nico` .

(from Josuttis, Nicolai M.. "The C++ Standard Library.")

My question is why in above mention case it is not guaranteed that memory of `"Nico"` object will be deleted at the end of the scope?

Although if we do this instead

```
whoMadeCoffee.resize(2);
pNico = nullptr;
```

The memory associated with `"Nico"` does get deleted.

Can someone please explain the difference?

Comment: I don't really understand the question, there is no scope in your example...

Comment: It looks like you misunderstand what the sentence from the book means. For the sake of completeness, please include the sentence that immediately follows, and try to interpret the two togetger.

Comment: @OznOg this is a extract from the book and code is only this much.

Comment: @n.m. I have added extra text from the book, I hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: @Espionage It is being deleted unless you have serious issues with the compiler - which is unlikely. Why do you think that it is not being deleted? How do you even test it?

Comment: @ALX23z I don't know why this should happen, but the book says so.

Comment: In this case deletion indeed does not happen at the end of the scope, it happens **earlier**.

Comment: I think the confusion is about the sentence "Such a deletion does not necessarily have to happen at the end of the scope". I think Espionage understood, that the deletion itself does not happen at all if it does not happen at the end of scope. But the sentence means "not necessarily at the end of scope, but can also happen earlier".

Comment: @VTT/churill Ohh yes I misunderstood I think I understand it now, many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> At the end of the program, when the last owner of the string gets
>   destroyed, the shared pointer calls delete for the object it refers
>   to. Such a deletion does not **necessarily** have to happen at the end
>   of the scope.

`string("Nico")` will be destroyed when the reference count reaches 0. In your example it reaches to 0 (for Nico) even before reaching the end of scope.

It can live out of its scope if you share with somebody else out of your current scope for example having a function that returns a `shared_ptr` or here is an even simpler example:

```
shared_ptr<string> pNico0(new string(""));
{ 
    shared_ptr<string> pNico1(new string("Nico"));
    pNico0 = pNico1; // pNico0 reference count = 2
}
// pNico0 reference count = 1
```

Live on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/N5XQPP)